# Android Expansion Files Library Setup

Tags: android, expansion

I have been trying to implement Expansion files unsuccessfully. I have included the libraries for Licensing, Expansion, and zip files as external jar files to the sample project and everything seems to be fine and all errors go away. When I run the program, however, I get an error that says:

"05-22 17:49:05.377: E/AndroidRuntime(10197): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.vending.expansion.downloader.R$string"

and the program crashes. How do I resolve this error so I can use test and then use the expansion library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The expansion files must be included as Android library projects rather than as jar files.  This allows for the resources used in the downloader library to be added to the resources of the main project.